# python: in my df, I need to add up a column until i hit a target, then change the data in a different column for each value that makes the target

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

`enter code here`I have a df like this :

```
   Project        position    emp   hrs
0        A  Burger flipper   John  1.25
1        B         cashier  steve  2.25
2        C         cleaner  Karen  0.25
3        A   shift manager  sally  0.25
4        C      supervisor  julie  1.25
5        A         cleaner  Karen  1.75**strong text**
6        B  Burger flipper   John  0.25
7        C  Burger flipper   John  7.50
8        A         cashier  steve  1.25
9        C         cleaner  Karen  0.50
10       A   shift manager  sally  0.75
11       B      supervisor  julie  0.75
12       C         cleaner  Karen  1.75
13       A  Burger flipper   John  2.25


I need to change it so that for emp John, 10 of his hours are registered as Restaurant Manager and the remaining are left as burger flipper.
```

Any help would be awesome.

have since tried the knapsack problem and tried to apply it to mine - i think my answer is in there somewhere

edit 3: so I have found a way to make add the numbers to find the target:

the numbers pulled from their own separate df for john:

0     1.25
6     0.25
7     7.50
13    2.25
14    3.25
20    4.75
21    0.25
27    0.50
28    0.50
34    2.25
35    2.75
Name: hrs, dtype: float64

then:
num = numbers
limit = 10

```
num = numbers
```

limit = 10

def sumofnums(limit, num):
sumofnums = 0
prefix = []
for i in num:
if sumofnums< limit:
sumofnums = sumofnums + i
prefix.append(i)
if sumofnums > limit:
return prefix

print(sumofnums(limit, num))

gives me this result:

[1.25, 0.25, 7.5, 2.25]

so now i need to work out how to display the index of each number returned so I can use that to go back and edit the position for each one. i think.

I am not holding much hope -I cant even work out how to make this page work properly - lol

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[:, 'cumsum'] = df.groupby('emp')['hrs'].transform('cumsum')

ind = df[(df['emp'] == 'John') & (df['cumsum'] < 10)].index
df.loc[ind, 'position'] = 'Restaurant Manager'

print(df)
```

Output

```
   Project            position    emp   hrs  cumsum
0        A  Restaurant Manager   John  1.25    1.25
1        B             cashier  steve  2.25    2.25
2        C             cleaner  Karen  0.25    0.25
3        A       shift manager  sally  0.25    0.25
4        C          supervisor  julie  1.25    1.25
5        A             cleaner  Karen  1.75    2.00
6        B  Restaurant Manager   John  0.25    1.50
7        C  Restaurant Manager   John  7.50    9.00
8        A             cashier  steve  1.25    3.50
9        C             cleaner  Karen  0.50    2.50
10       A       shift manager  sally  0.75    1.00
11       B          supervisor  julie  0.75    2.00
12       C             cleaner  Karen  1.75    4.25
13       A      Burger flipper   John  2.25   11.25
```

A 'cumsum' column is created: [grouped](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by 'emp', fetching the 'hrs' column, [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) is used.

Get row indices where 'John' and df['cumsum'] < 10.

Through explicit indexing [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) (indices on the left, column name on the right) values are set.